# Can't figure out a simple SQL query

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Might be very simple, but I've been digging fow a few days now...  I just can't figure out how to make this SQL query in Access...

In reference to the tables below, i'm looking for the query that can extract all the ITEMS for a specific Shop (ie 1:Alpha) from a specific GROUP (ie 1:Tools), that are NOT in the report for 2014... in this case ITEMS.IDs 6, 8, 9 and 10!

Tables:

```
Years
ID | Year
-----------------------------------------------
1 | 2014
2 | 2015

Shops
ID | ShopName
-----------------------------------------------
1 | Alpha
2 | Bravo

Items
ID | StockNbr | Description | GroupID
-----------------------------------------------
1 | 00-1200 | Ratchet 1/4 | 1
2 | 00-1201 | Ratchet 1/2 | 1
3 | 00-1300 | Screwdriver Philips No1 | 1
4 | 01-5544 | Banana | 2
5 | 00-4457 | Apple | 2
6 | 21-8887 | Hammer | 1
7 | 21-6585 | Drill | 1
8 | 21-4499 | Multimeter | 1
9 | 21-5687 | Digital Caliper | 1
10 | 22-7319 | File Set | 1
...

Groups
ID | GroupName
-----------------------------------------------
1 | Tools
2 | Fruits

REPORTS
ID | YearID | ShopID | ItemID
-----------------------------------------------
1 | 1 | 1 | 1
2 | 1 | 1 | 2
3 | 1 | 1 | 3
4 | 1 | 1 | 4
5 | 1 | 1 | 7
6 | 1 | 2 | 5
7 | 1 | 2 | 8
8 | 1 | 2 | 10
```

I've tried this, but then I realize it doesn't take the shops into consideration, it'll list all items that are not listed in reports, so if reports has an item for shop 2, it won't list it either...

```
SELECT Items.ID, Items.StockNbr, Items.Description, Items.GroupID, Reports.YearID, Reports.ShopID
FROM Reports
  RIGHT JOIN Items ON Reports.ItemID = Items.ID
WHERE (((Items.GroupID)=1) AND ((Reports.UnitID) Is Null))
ORDER BY Items.StockNbr;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for an anti-join. There are several ways to do this. Here's one using `not in`.

```
select i.* from items i
where i.GroupId = 1
and i.ID NOT IN (
    select ItemID from reports r
    where r.ShopID = 1
    and r.YearID = 2014
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much...  I knew it was easy!  I think I persisted in wanting to do it some other way, without even thinking of "anti-join"...

Answer (score 0):

If the table `Reports` does not reference Items.ID then there is no available relationship ShopID or YearID

```
select * 
from items
left join reports on items.id = reports.itemid
where reports.itemid IS NULL
```